# Vuex - update object in mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, vuex, mutation

After the user clicks a button I want to replace the data in my vuex store with the data from my local object. But I am stuck at the mutation. Here is some code for more details.

This is the method that is called after the user clicks a button.
(this.tableview is a local object with the same values as the vuex object)

```
            updateVuexTableview() {
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                console.log("Update Vuex Table view");
                this.updateTableview(this.tableview)
            }
```

In this method my vuex action is called. Which looks like this:
(updTableview is the new data that I want to insert)

```
async updateTableview({commit}, updTableview) {
        const response = await axios.put(
            `http://localhost:3000/tableview`,
            updTableview
        );

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log(response.data);

        commit('updateTableviewMut', response.data);
    },
```

This is the mutation that is called. That's where I am stuck. I have tried to pop the data and push it again, but nothing works so far.

```
    updateTableviewMut: (state, updTableview) => {
        state.tableview.push(updTableview)
    },
```

This right here is my state:

```
const state = {
    tableview: {
        "thema_c": true,
        "status_c": true,
        "priority_c": true,
        "custom1_c": true,
        "custom2_c": true,
        "customFieldName1": "Custom1",
        "customFieldName2": "Custom2"
    },
};
```

Comment: `state.tableview` is not an array its an object so you can't use `.push` on that

Comment: So you are able to get to `updateTableviewMut` ?

Comment: Yes the mutation is called.
I know how to update an array element but not an object.

Comment: You cannot update an object like that you can update an object like this, `state.tableview['keyname'] = updTableview` where you have to give a keyname to that item. Also can you update how your `updTableview` looks like

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! `state.tableview = updTableview` works for me. Didn't thought it would be so easy.

Comment: Welcome @HTLWelsITLover99. Its good that it solve your problem. Can I ask you to accept my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot update an object by `.push` you have to reassign object or set a specific field.
Just change your code like this:
If you want to add a key value pair you can do:

```
updateTableviewMut: (state, updTableview) => {
  state.tableview['keyname'] = updTableview
}
```

Or if you want to reassign an object you can do:

```
updateTableviewMut: (state, updTableview) => {
  state.tableview = updTableview
}
```